# how to get the rowindex by rowid in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]

im pulling this data from

const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

in rowdata i have full data like below
[image]

Comment: Describe the context of _"how"_. Where are you trying to use the index? What do you hope to do with it? Where is the code for that? Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).